# delete a Firebase user using C#

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to delete a user account in Firebase in C#?
I can successfully create users but on the delete, I get INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION bu I don't know how to provide the correct permissions.

The code for creating a user:

```
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(NEW_USER_URL);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            var body = new
            {
                email = email,
                password = password
            };

            string json = JObject.FromObject(body).ToString();

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
```

The code for deleting a user:

```
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(DELETE_USER_URL);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            var body = new
            {
                localId = uUid
            };

            string json = JObject.FromObject(body).ToString();

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

The urls:

```
    static string NEW_USER_URL = $@"https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key={ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FireBaseProjectApiKey"]}";
    static string DELETE_USER_URL = $@"https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/deleteAccount?key={ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FireBaseProjectApiKey"]}";
```

Comment: There are no documented public REST APIs to create or delete a user in Firebase Authentication.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion and decided to write a node server to do the Firebase usermanagement and invoke him from C#.